# How to make a chrome extension listen to mongodb document changes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, google-chrome-extension

I am building a link syncing chrome extension. I managed to push the links to mongodb database using a custom made REST API. When a document changes in mongodb database, I am able to listen to those changes using **change stream** in the custom made REST API. However, I am unable to pass those changes to the chrome extension, when a document change occurs in the database.

Is there any way, to make a chrome extension listen to changes in mongodb database and get those changes as soon as the change occurs?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a Chrome extension listen for changes in a MongoDB database, but this will require some additional work on your part. One way to do this would be to use the WebSocket API to create a persistent connection between your Chrome extension and your custom REST API. Your REST API can then use the MongoDB change stream to listen for changes in the database and pass those changes back to the Chrome extension over the WebSocket connection. This way, the Chrome extension can receive real-time updates from the database as soon as changes occur.

Alternatively, you could use polling to periodically check for changes in the database and update the extension accordingly. This approach would not provide real-time updates, but it would be easier to implement and may be sufficient for your needs, depending on the specific requirements of your extension.